# Why does Sublime Text (2.0.2) connect to the Internet (and on port 80)?

Tags: sublimetext2

Why is my text editor, trying to make an insecure connection to the Internet? It happens when the application is opened. This is a screen shot from Little Snitch.

[image: blocked connection]

Comment: Do you have automatically check for updates on? Sublime will also check to see if your copy is registered periodically.

Comment: And possibly consults the complete help docs and manual on the server

Comment: ...and logging my IP address every time I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked using Fiddler and as @Timeout suspected, it is checking for updates by submitting the following GET to www.sublimetext.com:

`GET http://www.sublimetext.com/updates/2/stable/updatecheck?version=2221&platform=windows&arch=x64&r=1 HTTP/1.1`

It responds with the latest version that is available:

`{
    "latest_version": 2221,
    "update_url": "http://www.sublimetext.com/2"
}`